# Find Ip address of secondary router

Tags: lan, wireless-access-point, ip-address

So, in my college, each room has 1 LAN port. Since the rooms themselves house 2 people, me and my roommate bought a router (MI 4a gigabit). Every router in my college needs to be configured by the computer center since using it directly seems to cause problems with all the other devices connected to the same switch.

Since the configuration was not done before me, I do not know what they actually did. What I can tell you is the following:

1. They asked to connect the ethernet to the LAN port of the router and not the WAN port.
2. The IP address to each device connected to the network are unique and not shared.
3. I can see other people's devices in the network (presumably in the same network switch), which are not connected through my router.
4. The assigned IP address range that I can see: 172.16.132-134.1-255

What I want to do is access the configuration page of my router to find out more details about the setup.

My router also has a wired repeater mode in which the LAN is supposed to be connected to WAN, so I was wondering if it would be better to use than instead of the LAN-LAN thing they currently are using?

Comment: You might be able to find your router's IP address with Advanced IP Scanner (Famatech).  Otherwise your question is off topic because it is your school's setup and you need to contact them.

Comment: If they asked to connect the wall port to a lan port on the router then it's acting as a switch, not a router. Therefore, the settings on it have no function at all. The wan port will have no IP address against it. You could have saved some money by just buying a cheap switch.

Comment: Use `tracert google.com` - the first entry might be your router (when you are connected to it)..

Comment: +1 you need a switch not a Router.  As long as you use the lan ports on the router for all connections and disable DHCP etc. on the router, it works (i.e. as a switch).

Comment: So if it is working as a switch, does that mean the router settings don't exist? Also is it better than using wired repeater mode?